# When did the universe become lighter than water at 1 g/cm3

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, estimation

1. Did the universe become lighter than water before light could travel through it?
2. What temperature was it at the time where matter was roughly 1g/cm3?

Comment: This is a homwork type question. The expansion of the scale factor in time goes as $1/(1+z)$. Can you work out $z$ at the epoch of (re)combination? Wien's law tells you that temperature goes as 1/wavelength, i.e. 1/scale factor.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Thank you! It was for a layman's theological study and for curiousity, i want to find a page which has laymans term description of inflation, i.e. the time taken to go from 5g/cm3, same as metals to 1g/cm3, and to know the temperature at physical terms used for material existing at that time, it's nice to understand the inflation in comparison to terrestrial temperatures, pressures and times.

Comment: Inflation is all over at densities many, many orders of magnitude higher than that. You also need to specify what you mean by "matter" - normal matter or all gravitating matter? The answer to your first Q is that the density of matter (total or otherwise) is only $1100^3$ higher than it is now. 20 orders of magnitude lower than water.

Comment: You need redshifts of $10^{10}$ for the matter density to increase to that of water. The temperature goes up correspondingly (from 2.7 K now). However, the universe is dominated by radiation at this point. If you include the density due to this, the temperature would be just a bit less than a billion degrees at 1 g/cc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did the universe become lighter than water before light could travel
>   through it? What temperature was it at the time where matter was
>   roughly 1g/cm3?

If by light could travel through it, that you mean the cosmic background radiation period, then, the answer is yes, the universe was much lighter than the density of water by then and it wasn't even close.   The current density of the universe by this [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe):

> 9.9×10−30 g/cm3 (equivalent to 6 protons per cubic meter of space

errors were pointed out in my density calculation at the time of CMB, so I've removed that part.

I also found [this](http://www.as.utexas.edu/astronomy/education/fall09/scalo/secure/301F09.Ch27slides.pdf), and I can't swear by it's accuracy, but it's probably not too far off.  Scroll down to page 6.  It suggests a density of 10^4 km/m^3 during the photon epoch at about 100 seconds.  The density of water is 10^3 km/m^3, so, figure, not too long after 100 seconds.   Somewhere in the range of a few to a handful of minutes should be about right as a ballpark answer, long before light traveled through the universe.   A universe with the density of water would be very hot and very different than the universe we know.   The chart also gives a temperature of a billion degrees at 100 seconds, so that gives a rough ballpark estimate.  It doesn't work out the math though.

Comment: Your numbers are more than a little off. The current diameter is 46 *billion* light years. Also, the CMB was emitted at a redshift of $z = 1000$, so the universe was $1000^3$ times more dense then than now. In general light at a redshift of $z$ was emitted when the linear size of the universe relative to today was $a = 1/(1+z)$. Because the universe has been expanding at a non-constant rate, comparisons of diameters and ages doesn't generally work.

Comment: Also, only about $5\%$ of that $9.9\times10^{-30}\ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$ is the sort of regular matter we usually think of.

Comment: @ChrisWhite, yes, I forgot to write billion, that's an error of 9 magnitudes.   Also I wrote diameter when I should have written radius.  Both fixed.     I will admit, I don't quite grok the redshift of 1,000, so if you want to explain that, feel free, cause I can't.  But even multiplying the current density by a billion, the density is still way way way below the density of water.

Comment: Yes, the result holds that the universe was very dilute at the time. What I'm saying though is that what is 46 billion light years across now was 46 million, not 14 billion, light years across when the CMB formed. The 1000 is just the redshift of the CMB, and the formula for getting the size of the universe then is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_%28cosmology%29).

Comment: I'm happy to say that while I mess up from time to time, I've not yet had the honor of being off by a factor of 10^9.  But then, I'm also not a physicist.  ;)

Comment: My mistake on answering a homework question, but, for what it's worth, it's a pretty stupid homework question.   I'd say just as bad as adding up the temperatures of stars that Feynman criticized in one of his books.   Not a good physics question.     @RobJeffries   I always welcome correction but you've said "a lot of this" is wrong before as a criticism and it's not helpful.   My intention was to educate.  Yours should be too.

Comment: I have educated. See my comment to the OP. I have no duty to correct answers and Chris White had already done so.